# What are the differences between osql, isql, and sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, command-line

I am interested in using some kind of a command-line utility for SQL Server similar to Oracle's SQL*Plus. SQL Server seems to have several options: osql, isql, and sqlcmd. However, I am not quite certain which one to use.

Do they all essentially do the same thing? Are there any situations where it is preferable to use one over the others?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use sqlcmd-- it's the most fully featured product.

- **sqlcmd**: The newest, fanciest command-line interface to SQL Server.
- **isql** : The older, DB-Library (native SQL Server protocol) way of command-line communication with SQL Server.
- **osql** : The older, ODBC-based way of command-line communication with SQL Server.

**EDIT:**  Times have changed since I replied on this a couple of years ago.  Nowadays, you can also use the [invoke-sqlcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx) cmdlet in PowerShell.  If you're used to PowerShell or plan to do any scripting of any sophistication, use this instead.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure what the scope of your question is, but I believe :

isql used DB-Library to communicate to the server and is no longer included after SQL2000

osql used ODBC to communicate to the server and will no longer included after SQL2005

sqlcmd used OLE DB to communicate to the server and is currently the recommended command line tool.

Comment: `osql` is still included: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\OSQL.EXE`

Comment: osql is still included in SQL2016, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\OSQL.EXE

Comment: @Rick I don't have OSQL in 2016. I checked that folder, and under 130 or 140, I have no such program. I even did a search for the whole SQL Server folder and that never came up. All my commands using OSQL also fail. So i just switched to SQLCMD

Comment: @LearnByReading I believe those tools are only installed with SQL2016 if you check the appropriate feature during installation... "Client SDK Tools" I believe. If not, you can also install them separately via a command line tool installer found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676

Answer (score 5):

Its always better to use SQLCMD instead of OSQL or ISQL if you have SQL SERVER 2005, otherwise use OSQL instead of ISQL.

Microsoft has announced before that ISQL was on its way out. Sure enough, ISQL is not included in SQL Server 2005 RTM. OSQL eventually will be phased out also, although it is still included in SQL Server 2005 binary install. With the historical SQL Server release cycle in mind, maybe OSQL will bid us adieu in 2010.

SQLCMD has many advantages as below:

- 1) Performance wise
- 2) SQLCMD supports parameterized variables
- 3) SQLCMD support Customized editor
- 4) :XML [ONOFF]
- 5) :Error STDERRSTDOUT
- 6) :Perftrace STDERRSTDOUT
- 7) Remote Dedicated Admin Connection (DAC)

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tool "SQLS*Plus" (on http://www.memfix.com ) which is exactly like Oracle SQL*Plus for SQL Server. Works with all SQL Server versions.

Very flexible with data formatting (set lines size, pagesize, etc), variables (var, &, &&), spool, HTML output, etc -  lots of added functionality comparing to isql, osql or sqlcmd