# How to execute stored procedure from a file?

Tags: stored-procedures

I'm trying to figure out how to run a stored procedure that I have in a separate file from create database script.

I'm trying to avoid placing stored procedure script directly into create database script as I will have the same code into 2 places.

Does anyone know how to execute stored procedure from file?

Comment: Strictly speaking, if it isn't part of the database then it isn't really a stored procedure. Why not just run it as a piece of standalone SQL?

Comment: Mssql. I have a file that I run from my code that creates database and I also need to create couple store procedures when that new database is created.

Comment: So just add them to the database and then execute them. Or if you don't want them to be part of the database then run them as standalone scripts...

Comment: I'm running a script and not physically creating database. Is there a command that I can use that will open a file and run stuff from that file?

Comment: It depends on what version of SQL Server you're running. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338293/what-are-the-differences-between-osql-isql-and-sqlcmd